# Convert java.util.Set of <key,value> object to simple pojo object

Tags: java, collections, set, mapping

Getting a java.util.Set of objects which has only key-value pairs as input like below

```
public class KeyValueObject {
String key;
String value;

// good old constructor, setters and getters

}
```

Input Object:
    java.util.Set inputObject;

```
KeyValuePair pair1 = new KeyValuePair("Name":"John");
KeyValuePair pair2 = new KeyValuePair("Age":"28");
KeyValuePair pair3 = new KeyValuePair("Location":"Cincinnati");

inputObject.add(pair1);
inputObject.add(pair2);
inputObject.add(pair3);
```

With the "inputObject" as the request coming in, how to convert this to a simple POJO object which has all the keys described above as individual parameters like below:

```
Public class SimplePojoObject {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String location;

  // Good old setters and getters

}
```

The incoming object has around 52 objects and that is why the manual way of mapping is not the right way to solve this issue. Please suggest on any possible way of mapping this data

Comment: Write an [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). Sidenote: it's `java.util.Set`, not `Java.Util.Set`.

Comment: @Turing85: I have now written an adapter Utsav_Deep's answer. Also, I updated the Java.Util.Set to be java.util.Set to be accurate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- Convert `Set<KeyValueObject>` to a `JsonNode` (or `Map<String, String>`) object.
- Convert the generated `JsonNode` (or `Map<String, String>`) object to `SimplePojoObject` using `ObjectMapper` (you can also use Gson library instead of ObjectMapper)

If you already have a `Map<String, String>` object instead of `Set<KeyValueObject>` then you can do it in just one line:

```
SimplePojoObject simplePojoObject = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(map, SimplePojoObject.class);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have used this as the method to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to write a small method that calls the setters:

```
public SimplePojoObject buildSimplePojoObject(Set<KeyValuePair> properties) {
    SimplePojoObject result = new SimplePojoObject();
    for (KeyValuePair prop : properties) {
        switch (prop.getKey()) {
            case "Name":
                result.setName(prop.getValue());
                break;
            case "Age":
                result.setAge(prop.getValue());
                break;
            case "Location":
                result.setLocation(prop.getValue());
                break;
            default:
                // Throw an exception or ignore it.
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown property "+ prop.getKey());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But if you want to do that dynamically, you certainly could:

```
public SimplePojoObject buildSimplePojoObject(Set<KeyValuePair> properties) {
    SimplePojoObject result = new SimplePojoObject();
    Lookup l = MethodHandles.publicLookup();
    MethodType mt = MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class);
    for (KeyValuePair prop : properties) {
        MethodHandle mh = l.findVirtual(SimplePojoObject.class, "set" + prop.getKey());
        try {
            mh.invokeExact(result, prop.getValue());
        } catch (Error | RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // MethodHandle.invokeExact is declared to throw Throwable, so we have to catch it.
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering my question. Even though this does the job, I used Utsav_deep's solution to resolve the issue.